Reload books in Books App
I have a (large) number of epub books in my Books App. These books come from non-book store sources, so they’re on my disk.
I can access these books using the Books folder on iCloud. In some cases, I have had to make a few edits (such as changing the background colour of pages). I can do this using an application called “Magic” which appears to be related to Sigil.
After I save the changes, how can I make sure the the Books app reloads the book with changes? When I look at the book after the changes, they don’t appear unless I remove and add the book again, which seems a lot of extra work.
I’m editing the books on my Mac and testing on the Mac Books app. In real life, I read the books on my iPad.
